# Exception parsing document error while using Thymeleaf

Tags: base64, thymeleaf

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Hello Thymeleaf!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
        <img th:src="@{data:image/jpeg;base64, /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/7QCEUGhvdG9zaG9wI...
    }">
    </body>
</html>
```

I am displaying an image which is converted to Base64 (MIME type conversion) format and I am using Thyme-leaf template, can someone figure out what's happening?

Comment: Please giv us more information about the exception. Do you have a stacktrace or something?

Comment: Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Oct 09 12:44:16 IST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception parsing document: template="hello", line 15 - column 3

Comment: I am rendering this html file from spring boot Java project using Thyme leaf as template @BenjaminSchüller

Comment: Ok, i guess line 15 is the line with img-Tag? Do you have any output on console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible error could be that thymeleaf check the html-syntax strict and you don't close your image-tag. So try to change it like this:

```
<img th:src="@{data:image/jpeg;base64, /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQ... }" />
```